# How to create a REST api and deploy it in cloud?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am learning software development. As a part of learning, I've created an aws account to create a REST api. I'm still new to aws cloud and wanted to make sure ,I'm doing it correctly. I'm utilizing API gateway to create a REST Endpoint which triggers a serverless lambda. I'm in US WEST region, but say if I have users in US EAST, do I need to go and create/set up same gateway and lambda for US EAST reason, such that response time is better for east region?

for now,  I chose "Edge" endpoint type for Endpoint type for my api gateway. I understand this is also an option, if we are deploying in just one region. I would like to add some firewall rules via WAF/WEB ACL to my api. does it matter if the endpoint type is "Edge" vs "Regional"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it matters if the endpoint is edge or regional, as specified in the documentation [1] for edge endpoint the "API requests are routed to the nearest CloudFront Point of Presence (POP). This is the default endpoint type for API Gateway REST APIs."

And for regional, "If you deploy a regional API in multiple regions, it can have the same custom domain name in all regions. You can use custom domains together with Amazon Route 53". Also in the below documentation [1] you can find the link on how to do this.

[1]https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-endpoint-types.html

Comment: @Daniel - thanks , i will go through thelinks you have provided. but edge or regional,  the process of adding a WAF /web ACL should be the same and work the same way right?

Comment: @kyagu please go to this link [1] to see how to set up a regional custom domain name in API Gateway, you would still need to setup WAF / web ACL for security measures.
[1]https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-regional-api-custom-domain-create.html